# Centering three rectangles of different size

Tags: math, graphics

If I have 3 different sprites, that each belongs to the same sprite but with different animations type. Each has a different width, height, in the sprite sheet.

How do I adjust the 3 using math, to let them be centered, and overlapped on each other, so that when I can change their animation, and all animations are overlapped on each other. I would like to get the x,y for each sprite then, that result all of them have the same position.

Comment: Why do you need to post it on two different sites?
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68936/centering-three-rectangles-of-different-size

Comment: @Andrea and what's the problem with that ? gamedev !=stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode. Translate to your preferred language.

```
Let wi and hi be width and height of ith image, i = 1, 2, 3.
Let (x1, y1), ..., (x3, y3) be the coordinates of the top left corner of each image.

    wmax = max(w1, w2, w3)
    hmax = max(h1, h2, h3)

        x1 = round((wmax - w1) / 2)  // Depending on your language and your purposes, floor or ceil.    
        y1 = round((hmax - h1) / 2)  // Similar comment as x

    // Similarly for (x2, y2) and (x3, y3)

    // Add offset if necessary

    Let (x0, y0) be offset to add to top left corner of image.

    (xi, yi) = (xi + x0, yi + y0)
```

Comment: thanks!. Still there is a slight offset between all the animations in the Y Axis. I have translated all the sprites into the same x,y. but still there are few pixels are off

Comment: Only for the Y axis? How many pixels are off? If it is one then it could be due to the rounding. Note that if you are using integer division then the rounding has no effect.